# Raspberry PI not connects to SSH

Tags: ssh, connection, raspberry-pi

I just got my Raspberry PI and I want to use in headless mode(it's better for me and I don't have an HDMI monitor). I connect my PI to laptop normally, I can ping it, I can find it on the web browser, but I can't connect as SSH. Please help me!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have not installed ssh server 
check that, if not : 
try in Terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install openssh-server 
reload ssh
```

Answer (score 0):

[How to enable SSH on Raspberry Pi](http://www.raspberrypi.org/documentation/remote-access/ssh/)